# Javascript Combine Two Columns of Names into One Column in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I am scraping a list of names from a website table using Data Miner. I am trying to add the names into an Excel column. The names being scraped are in a Last Name, First Name format. Below are some of the names for reference. I would like to rearrange the names so the first name comes before the last name and remove the comma. I have been able to split the names, adding the first name in column 1 and the last name in column 2 using the code below. I can not bring the names back into the first column. If someone could show me how to do this that would be great. Also, Mr. Ted Potter Jr. has 2 commas in his name. What can I do to make sure the formatting matches the rest of the names but leave the comma between Potter and Jr.?

- An, Byeong Hun
- Ancer, Abraham
- Anderson, Mark
- Armour, Ryan
- Baddeley, Aaron
- Baker, Chris
- Barnes, Ricky
- Berger, Daniel
- Potter, Jr., Ted

  var cleanup = function(results) {

  // This example shows you can loop through each 
    // row of the data you scraped results and change the value each column

  //debugger;  // uncomment this line to enable debugging your script in Chrome Inspector

  $.each(results, function(){                // loop through each row of scraped data

  ```
  var parts = this.values[0].split(', ');   // get value from column 1 and split it by ' '
            var first_name = parts[parts.length - 1];

      //Loop through the remaining elements
      //for "Baker, Chris" this will just be one loop
      var second_name = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
          //if i = 0 then just add the element otherwise
          //if i > 0 then add what is already there plus space plus next element
          if (i > 0) {
              //this.values[1] = this.values[1] + " " + parts[i];
              second_name  = second_name + ", " + parts[i];
          }else {
              //this.values[1] = parts[i];
              second_name = parts[i];
          }
      }

  this.values[0] = first_name + " " + second_name;
  ```

  console.log(this.values[0]);
    });

  return results;                            // return modified results
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell without the context/some more code but in general, I think something like this would work.

If you want a real example see here: https://jsfiddle.net/pqjd2h5a/

- Do your split
- Put the last element of the array to the front / to column 1
- Loop through the remaining elements and concatenate them together at column 2
- Concatenate first name and last name(s) together in column 3

Maybe something like this:

```
var cleanup = function(results) {

$.each(results, function(){
    //split the string of "Baker, Chris" into an array of ["Baker", "Chris"]
    //split the string of "Potter, Jr., Ted" into an array of ["Potter", "Jr.", "Ted"]
    var parts = this.values[0].split(', ');

    //set the first column to the last element of the array. i.e. "Chris" or "Ted"
    //this.values[0] = parts[parts.length - 1];
    var first_name = parts[parts.length - 1];

    //Loop through the remaining elements
    //for "Baker, Chris" this will just be one loop
    var second_name = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
        //if i = 0 then just add the element otherwise
        //if i > 0 then add what is already there plus space plus next element
        if (i > 0) {
            //this.values[1] = this.values[1] + " " + parts[i];
            second_name  = second_name + " " + parts[i];
        }else {
            //this.values[1] = parts[i];
            second_name = parts[i];
        }
    }
    //concatenate the results together in the third column
    //i.e. "Chris Baker" or "Ted Potter Jr."
    //this.values[2] = this.values[0] + " " + this.values[1];

    //Or now output only in first column
    this.values[0] = first_name + " " + second_name;
});

return results;};
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response. For some additional context, I am trying to create a spreadsheet for a fantasy golf league. I am trying to scrape the information for the pga FedEx Cup standings and compare them to the tournament field so I can rank the players of that tournament based on where they are in the FedEx Cup standings. The standings have the names in a First Name" "Last Name format. I have already set up Data Miner to scrape this information from the pga tour website. The tournament field list is in the format that I described in the question.

Comment: I am needing the two in the same format so I can use some index match formulas in excel to compare the two.

Comment: Ok so I anticipate your first row would be "An, Byeong Hun" and my code would give you:
|    Byeong Hun    |    An    |    Byeong Hun An    |

And your last row "Potter, Jr., Ted" would give you
|    Ted    |    Potter Jr.    |    Ted Potter Jr.    |

Is this not the right format? What format would you like?

Comment: We could easily change the index of the lines to change which column the data goes in. Like `this.values[0] = parts[parts.length - 1];` could easily be `this.values[1] = parts[parts.length - 1];` etc. however you like the data.

Comment: That is the correct format. I'd prefer the data show only the concatenated names in the first column. Could this be done by setting the arrays to variables like `var x = parts[this.value[1]];` and `y = parts[this.value[2]];` then reference the variables in the final index like `this.values[0] = x.concat(" ", y);`

Comment: yeah you could certainly do that. Or you could never save the values to `this.values[1]` or `this.values[2]` and just save them in variables as you go along and save them into `this.values[0]` - I made that change in the code now above. If my answer solves your question please consider to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Awesome. I copied your code into the JS section of Data Miner. There were a few errors that popped up (line 15 threw an expected ";" instead saw 'to' and expected ";" instead saw ')', line 18 threw an expected ')' to match '(' from line 18 and instead saw '>', expected '}' to match '{' from line 15 and instead saw ')', and expected ')' to match '(' from line 15 and instead saw '{', and line 21 threw expected but saw 'else' and I was able to mess around with it a bit (I added semicolons and a condition in the for loop) for errors to go away, but the code doesn't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: sorry too much time writing python, I forgot my semi-colons and forgot how to create a javacript for-loop. Oops! Let me edit my code. Do you have a JSFiddle to test it on (like this https://jsfiddle.net/76cnL3gm/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pqjd2h5a/ Check out this code sandbox, with the working example

Comment: JSFiddle will be very useful! Thanks for the reference. Your code works perfectly in the sandbox. The names are now showing up in the excel file but the formatting stays with LastName, FirstName when I run it from the Data Miner Chrome browser extension. Is there something I need to remove or add before running it?

Comment: If the code works perfectly in the Sandbox can you see how you would adapt/integrate that to your specific use case? I don't know/have never used Data Miner Chrome Extension. What is supposed to happen? results is an array with some HTML text and then you clean it up with your function and modify results directly and then return that and that gets exported to Excel?

Comment: Yeah I will try to play around with it for a bit. The scraper uses JQuery to identify the information and then presents it in the form of .csv or .xls files. I believe it's pretty much what you described.

Comment: So what I get from the current code is that the function takes the array and rearranges the names and then returns the text but keeps the original HTML data. Maybe that is why it is pulling the names in the original format? Do we need to do a .getElementsbyClassName(player-name) and quasi replace the HTML text and then pull the data? the class names of  the information needed are .player-block for the rows and .player-name for the columns.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like you just needed to add one closing bracket? If my answer helped you to answer your questions, please consider marking it as the correct answer and up-voting it.